# How to remove queued coordinator jobs in oozie?

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

While testing the jobs, I submitted multiple jobs by mistake which are running at regular intervals now. I should have tested with -dryrun option. I want to remove all those scheduled jobs from the queue so that they don't run on the next scheduled (next materialization). I tried killing the job using below command. Still it show as Succeeded in the oozie console. Am I missing something here? 
Please help.

```
oozie job -kill <-C_id>
```

Comment: Your command is correct. Are you sure coordinator job is still not killed? Make sure to double check your coordinator job id.

Comment: Many a times, the OOZIE URL path is not configured when using Oozie Command line; make sure you have that.

Answer (score 1):

Following is what I use to remove a coordinator job.

```
oozie job -oozie http://<OOZIE_URL>:11000/oozie -kill <-C_id>
```

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Killing_a_Workflow_Coordinator_or_Bundle_Job